# PHPExcel converting multiple sheet of xlsx to csv

Tags: php, phpexcel

im using this few lines to convert an xlsx, which contain 4sheets to convert to .csv . but it only convert the first sheet of the xlsx file. how can i make it to convert every sheets in the xlsx. heres the code,

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
    date_default_timezone_set($this->vendor_timezone);

    /** PHPExcel_IOFactory */

    require_once sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir').'/lib/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

    $file=sfConfig::get("sf_upload_dir").DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."temp".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."1344500254_MyExcel.xlsx"; 

    // Check prerequisites
    //print sfConfig::get("sf_upload_dir").DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."temp".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; exit;
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        exit($file."Please run 06largescale.php first.\n");
    }

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');

    $objWriter->save(str_replace('.xlsx', '.csv',$file));
    return "success";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert all sheets you must iterate through all worksheets and set it as the active sheet and then write that to a file.

```
$inFile = 'fileWithMultipleWorksheet.xlsx';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inFile);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');    

$index = 0;
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($index);

    // write out each worksheet to it's name with CSV extension
    $outFile = str_replace(array("-"," "), "_", $worksheet->getTitle()) .".csv";

    $objWriter->setSheetIndex($index);
    $objWriter->save($outFile);

    $index++;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Please check the tutorial here which has step by step code to achieve this

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("test123.xlsx");
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
$writer->setDelimiter(";");
$writer->setEnclosure("");
$writer->save("test123.csv");
?>
```

Comment: Entire Row in excel sheet is converting into single index, all columns become single value

Answer (score 1):

Write each sheet in turn to a different file, and then concatenate those files into one: PHPExcel does not provide an option to write multiple sheets to a single CSV file.

Comment: oh thats why. too bad. i've specified the sheet first before convert it using <pre>$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);</pre> . many thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear there is no way to write to a single CSV but if you look at my answer, you can easily write each sheet to a different CSV file.